# How do you read input line of text in python and make an array out of those elements and assign last digit to a variable?

Tags: python

You are given as input lines of a file containing a list and integer which is associated with a variable.
line = 1,2,3,4;5

How do i go about making an array out of the first 4 elements [1,2,3,4] and assigning the last element 5 to variable K?

I wanted to split it and get this:
arr = [1,2,3,4]
k = 5

```
text = "1,2,3,4;5"
myList = text.split(";")
k = int(myList[-1])
myList.pop()

arr = myList
n = len(arr)

i = 0
 
while(i<n):
  
    left = i
    right = min(i + k - 1, n - 1)

    while (left < right):     
        arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[left]
        left+= 1;
        right-=1
    i+= k


for i in range(0, n):
    print(arr[i], end ="")
```

Thank you everyone. I just needed to split the input and change the type from string to integer.

Comment: You need to show us, in code, what you have have done so far.

Comment: I included it shortly after. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one line version using the `re` module:

```
import re
line = '1,2,3,4;5'
*arr, k = re.split('[,;]', line)
```

This gives:

```
 print(arr, k)
    ['1', '2', '3', '4'] 5
```

If you need the array (Python list) to be integers instead of strings, you can use:

```
arr = [int(s)  for s in arr]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can try:

```
x='1,2,3,4;5'.split(",")
last=int(x[-1].split(";")[1])
x[-1]=x[-1].split(';')[0]
print(x,last)
```

OR

```
x='1,2,3,4;5'.split(';')
print(list(x[0].split(',')),int(x[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi looking at the input you gave 1,2,3,4;5
If this is the input then:

```
(a,k) = input().split (";") #this will sperate 1,2,3,4 to arr and 5 to k
arr = a.split(",") #it sperate 1234 and makes a list
print(arr,r)
```

Please tell me if it works

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```py
>>> line = '1,2,3,4;5'
>>> arr, k = line.split(';')
>>> arr = arr.split(',')

>>> arr
['1', '2', '3', '4']

>>> k
5
```

`line.split(';')` will split the value separated by `;` into two lists.
`arr.split(',')` will then split all the value separated by `,`.